# Can't seem to be able to draw very small TikZ shapes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, lengths, dimensions

I'm trying to draw small labels fitting circles, or at least proportional to them. But I just can't seem to make them smaller than this for some reason:

[image: Example]

I get that there might be a physical limit to how small things can be, but I feel like it should be lower than what's on that picture.

Here's the code:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\newlength{\step}

\tikzset{
  buffer/.style={
    draw,
    shape border rotate=0,
    regular polygon,
    regular polygon sides=3,
    fill=red,
    node distance=1pt,
    minimum height=1pt
  }
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \setlength{\step}{\dimexpr 10cm / 18 \relax}

    \draw[step=\step] (0, 0) grid (10, 10);

    \draw[draw = white, fill = black, line width = 0.1mm]
      (2 * \step, 3 * \step)
      circle [radius = 0.2575cm]
      node[color = white, font={\fontsize{0.1pt}{12}\selectfont}] {1};
    \draw[draw = black, fill = white, line width = 0.1mm]
      (3 * \step, 3 * \step)
      circle [radius = 0.2575cm]
      node[color = black] {2};
    \draw[draw = white, fill = black, line width = 0.1mm]
      (4 * \step, 3 * \step)
      circle [radius = 0.2575cm];
    \draw (3 * \step, 3 * \step) node[
      minimum size=1pt,
      draw] {};
    \draw node[buffer] at (4 * \step, 3 * \step) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And, by the way, why are TikZ shapes set with `minimum size`? Shouldn't there be a `maximum size` as well? Why not just `size` as well?

Comment: Have a look at `inner sep`

Comment: Damn. I think that pretty much solves it, at least for the shapes. Do you know how to make really small fonts?

Comment: You could choose a scalable font, e.g. the `lmodern` package

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I think you've pretty much answered it. If manage to add something to fix the font, I think I would accept it as answer right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There is some padding between the content of the node and the shape drawn around it. You can adjust it by modifying the `inner sep` parameter
- If you want to use extreme font sizes (either small or big), it is often easier to use a scalable font, e.g. by loading the `lmodern` package

---

```
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\tikzset{
  buffer/.style={
    draw,
    shape border rotate=0,
    regular polygon,
    regular polygon sides=3,
    fill=red,
    node distance=1pt,
    minimum height=1pt
  }
}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt]
    \node[fill=black,font={\fontsize{0.1}{12}\selectfont}] at (0,0) {1};
    \node[draw] at (1,0) {};
    \node[buffer] at (2,0) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, you draw 3 dots... lol :-)

Comment: @Sigur Using . . .  would have been so much easier for the same result :)